# How do I create an Image component to upload an image and write it to the DAM?

Tags: file-upload, aem, dam

I am trying to write a component based on the foundation Image component that will write the image to the DAM instead of the "local" jcr node on file upload.  I also want it to activate the "DAM Update Asset" workflow so that it will create the different size renditions.  Can you use a listener to write it to the DAM or is there another or better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to just do it within the component itself. But an EventListener could be triggered if someone uploads an image. In this EventListener you can move the image to a defined folder in DAM and start the workflows you want programmatically. Then you update the component so it references the new DAM asset instead of a directly attached nt:file.
Depending on which configuration of the image component you use and which browser is used, the upload is a bit different. The file usually first gets stored in /tmp and then moved. I am not sure it this only happens if the dialog is closed. So the safest way would be to await this event, eg. a add/change event on the jcr:lastModified property.